# How to replace a string with data, from 2 arrays, in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, string, search, intersection

I have a simple string: `$StrOne = "There is my text.";`. And, I have 2 simple arrays, too:

```
$ArrOne = array (

"1" => "a",
"7" => "e",
"5" => "c",
"4" => "x",
"2" => "r"

);
```

-

```
$ArrTwo = array (

"7" => "k",
"9" => "z",
"1" => "y",
"3" => "x",
"2" => "b"

);
```

---

I want to replace `$StrOne` with values from `$ArrOne`, by values from `$ArrTwo`. There is my idea:

- Step 1. If there is a *group of letter* in `$StrOne` (what is existed in `$ArrOne`), search in `$ArrTwo` what value is attached which the same key  (what is existed in `$ArrOne`).
- Step 2. Replace all existed values (from **Step 1.**), with this function: `strtr();`.
- Step 3. Display new output string  (which is replaced completely, from **Step 2.**).

The output string is: `$StrTwo = "Thkrk is my tkxt.";`.

---

How to create a simple PHP function, that it will do it like this?

Comment: how about http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php ?

Comment: Show us your attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: @BeetleJuice, I have tried to solve my problem, by using this function:

`    $length = count($arrayOne);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
        $replacement[$arrayOne[$i]] = $arrayTwo[$i];
    }

    echo strtr($string, $replacement);`.

But, it works with a one-dimensional array only.

Comment: i think that all native php functions are good enough, do not worry, just use them

Comment: Note that these are not multi-dimensional arrays. They are one-dimensional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to use `array_intersect_key`, to find keys which present in both arrays.

Second we sort intersected arrays so their keys were in same order with `ksort`.

Third we use `array_combine` to create second parameter for `strtr` function.

Forth we use `strtr`:

```
$arrayOne = array (
    "1" => "a",
    "7" => "e",
    "5" => "c",
    "4" => "x",
    "2" => "r"
);

$arrayTwo = array (
    "7" => "k",
    "9" => "z",
    "1" => "y",
    "3" => "x",
    "2" => "b"
);

$keys = array_intersect_key($arrayOne, $arrayTwo);
ksort($keys);
$values = array_intersect_key($arrayTwo, $arrayOne);
ksort($values);

echo strtr('There is my text.', array_combine($keys, $values));
```

**Update**: for older versions try:

```
$replace = array();
foreach ($arrayOne as $k => $v) {
    // use isset if you want to replace something with empty string
    if (!empty($arrayTwo[$k])) {    
        $replace[$v] = $arrayTwo[$k];
    }
}

echo strtr('There is my text.', $replace);
```

Comment: I am sorry, I do not want to use these functions: [array_intersect_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) and [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php); because, my server is too *out of update*.

Comment: Your php is not php5?

Comment: Yes, my server still runs *PHP 4*. Would you mind to suggest another an another answer?

Comment: You can accept my answer instead of writing `+1`)))

Comment: I can not press to **+1**; but, I have accepted your answer.

Comment: I will do that in your stead :)

Comment: @trincot, There is an error-syntax, in *BeetleJuice*'s answer.

Comment: Yes, but only if you have a version of PHP below 5.3, which introduced the `use` clause syntax. But why do you tell me? I did not write any answer here...

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you can't use `array_intersect`. This is how I would do it:

```
//remove anything from $arrayOne that doesn't have a replacement
// in $arrayTwo
$arrayOne = array_filter(
    $arrayOne,
    function($k) use($arrayTwo){return isset($arrayTwo[$k]);},
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

//remove anything from $arrayTwo that doesn't have a match
//in $arraaOne
$arrayTwo = array_filter(
    $arrayTwo,
    function($k) use($arrayOne){return isset($arrayOne[$k]);},
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

//sort the keys so that matching keys will be in same position
ksort($arrayOne); ksort($arrayTwo);

//Now arrays have the same keys in the same position.
//It's safe to perform the replacement
$stringOut = str_replace($arrayOne,$arrayTwo,$stringInp);
```

[Live demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/72416965381e6baa9f9521bcf73350083b507bae)

Comment: My code doesn't have 26 lines. Besides, I checked before posting. I even gave you a link to a live demo so you can see it working for yourself.

Comment: On this line: `function($k) use($arrayTwo){return isset($arrayTwo[$k]);}`.

Comment: `use` needs version 5.3

Comment: aaah ok thank you trincot.  Sorry about that YeuSeChia. I was getting really confused, but now it makes sense. Good luck.